# how to trigger parent element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
<div class="gallery_images" id="10">
    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal9" tabindex="0">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://contest.geojidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/contest_entries/thumbnail-1680__1050__auto___wp-content_uploads_2015_01_ajax-forms.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

The url of the page is http://v9contest.geojidesign.com/?img=http://v9contest.geojidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/contest_entries/1680__1050__auto___wp-content_uploads_2015_01_ajax-forms-1.jpg

using jquery I want to get the image link from page url, if matches with the image url in html then trigger click event on parent of image which is anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to get url parameter and [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event to trigger click.

```js
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
var param = '';
if(searchParams.has('img')) // true
{
    param = searchParams.get('img')
}
var imgSrc = $('.img-fluid').attr('src');

if (param==imgSrc)
{
   $( '.img-fluid' ).parent().trigger( "click" );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery_images" id="10">
    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal9" tabindex="0">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://contest.geojidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/contest_entries/thumbnail-1680__1050__auto___wp-content_uploads_2015_01_ajax-forms.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```